# Ошибка ClassNotFoundException в методе readObject()

Tags: java, исключения, десериализация

Мне надо десериализовать объекты в список, но у меня вылазит ошибка

> Unhandled exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

на методе `readObject()`. Вот код:

```
public static ArrayList<Equipment> readBinaryFile(String path){
    ArrayList<Equipment> equipments = new ArrayList<>();
    try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))){
        int count = ois.readInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            equipments.add((Equipment)ois.readObject());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
    }
    return equipments;
}
```

Ошибка при компиляции:

> Error:(43, 57) java: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Можно полный эксепшен? Там где-то должно быть сказано какой именно класс не найден.

Comment: @talex обновил вопрос, но там все равно не указывает класс, который не найден

Comment: Вы определитесь, у вас ошибка при компиляции или при запуске?

Comment: @talex у меня изначально подсвечивается метод readObject() и то, что там написано, я указал изначально, а так как вам этого не хватило, я его запустил и то, что было написано в сообщении я указал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте

```
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
}
```